# lxml installation problems on Mac

Tags: installation, plone, lxml, buildout

I am trying to install collective.xdv on my Mac locally. I am following the instructions here: http://plone.org/products/collective.xdv/documentation/tutorial/advanced-xdv-theming/prerequisites

My site only works when I take out all references to collective.xdv in buildout.cfg. If I include references to collective.xdv then my site doesn't load and my log file says: ERROR Application Couldn't Install Five (I have seen online forums where people are getting this error message when installing other products. I have tried the fixes recommended but they didn't work for me.)

**EDIT:** the "Application Couldn't install Five" error seems to be a kind of generic one, hence the most likely important part of the traceback is: *ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/lxml-2.2.4-py2.6-macosx-10.4-i386.egg/lxml/etree.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/lxml-2.2.4-py2.6-macosx-10.4-i386.egg/lxml/etree.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture*

```
    2011-07-29T13:44:57 ERROR Application Couldn't install Five
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.12.11-py2.6-macosx-10.4-i386.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 671, in install_product
        initmethod(context)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.12.11-py2.6-macosx-10.4-i386.egg/Products/Five/__init__.py", line 31, in initialize
        zcml.load_site()
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.12.11-py2.6-macosx-10.4-i386.egg/Products/Five/zcml.py", line 51, in load_site
        _context = xmlconfig.file(file)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 647, in file
        include(context, name, package)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 546, in include
        processxmlfile(f, context)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 378, in processxmlfile
        parser.parse(src)
      File "/Applications/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
        xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
      File "/Applications/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
        self.feed(buffer)
      File "/Applications/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
        self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
      File "/Applications/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
        self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 357, in endElementNS
        self.context.end()
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 537, in end
        self.stack.pop().finish()
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 685, in finish
        actions = self.handler(context, **args)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.12.11-py2.6-macosx-10.4-i386.egg/Products/Five/fiveconfigure.py", line 74, in loadProducts
        handleBrokenProduct(product)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.12.11-py2.6-macosx-10.4-i386.egg/Products/Five/fiveconfigure.py", line 72, in loadProducts
        xmlconfig.include(_context, zcml, package=product)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 546, in include
        processxmlfile(f, context)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 378, in processxmlfile
        parser.parse(src)
      File "/Applications/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
        xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
      File "/Applications/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
        self.feed(buffer)
      File "/Applications/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
        self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
      File "/Applications/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
        self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 357, in endElementNS
        self.context.end()
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 537, in end
        self.stack.pop().finish()
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 685, in finish
        actions = self.handler(context, **args)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.2-py2.6.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 104, in includePluginsDirective
        includeZCMLGroup(_context, info, filename)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.2-py2.6.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 30, in includeZCMLGroup
        include(_context, filename, includable_package)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 546, in include
        processxmlfile(f, context)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 378, in processxmlfile
        parser.parse(src)
      File "/Applications/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
        xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
      File "/Applications/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
        self.feed(buffer)
      File "/Applications/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
        self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
      File "/Applications/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
        self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 357, in endElementNS
        self.context.end()
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 537, in end
        self.stack.pop().finish()
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 684, in finish
        args = toargs(context, *self.argdata)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 1376, in toargs
        args[str(name)] = field.fromUnicode(s)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/fields.py", line 229, in fromUnicode
        v = vt.fromUnicode(s)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/fields.py", line 139, in fromUnicode
        value = self.context.resolve(name)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 180, in resolve
        mod = __import__(mname, *_import_chickens)
      File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.xdv-1.0rc11-py2.6.egg/collective/xdv/transform.py", line 4, in <module>
        from lxml import etree
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/Applications/Plone/zinstance/parts/instance/etc/site.zcml", line 16.2-16.23
        ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Plone-4.0.1-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/configure.zcml", line 94.4-98.10
        ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.xdv-1.0rc11-py2.6.egg/collective/xdv/configure.zcml", line 25.4-28.10
        ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/lxml-2.2.4-py2.6-macosx-10.4-i386.egg/lxml/etree.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Applications/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/lxml-2.2.4-py2.6-macosx-10.4-i386.egg/lxml/etree.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Answer (score 2):

Your lxml egg seems to have build/compile problem, which is common for OS X folk.  Try this:

http://plone.org/documentation/error/python-crashes-on-mac-os-x-lxml-related

Comment: According that link you should build your own static version and that is exactly what I did. I have also reinstalled Plone and gone through the whole of process of making static lxml egg several times.

Comment: I just did another fresh install and rebuild and got this from terminal: Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /opt/local/lib

Comment: Perhaps try specifying a newer version of lxml (2.3 is latest)?

Comment: Can you do this? virtualenv-2.6 test-lxml ; cd test-lxml ; bin/easy_install lxml ? I.e. does this complete successfully at least?

Comment: Sorry, I did not check back. I thought I had posted a comment here, saying I got it to work. I ended up using the unified installer with lxml version 2.3. Thanks!